# How to create new alerts in azure for all webapps at same time

Tags: azure-rm-template

I want to create new alerts(High CPU,RAM) for all AppServicePlans in a given subscription. I could not find Powershell commands to create new alerts. Is there a way we can create these alerts for all appserviceplans with a single script? May be using ARM template?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Add-AzMetricAlertRule` to create new alerts for your webapp? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrule?view=azps-2.1.0

Comment: No it does not work. I even tried Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2. It ask me to enter action ID and when i do that it simply gives me error:  Cannot convert the "actionGroupID" value of type "System.String" to type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for pasting a direct answer, but I cannot yet comment. You get the error because in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-2.3.2) for Add-AzMetricAlertruleV2 it states: "$act is the output of New-AzActionGroup cmdlet". Meaning you need to use for example:

```
$act = New-AzActionGroup -ActionGroupId "testActionGroup"
```

After that you need to add it in the parameter `-ActionGroup $act` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks Kristian. I got it working already. The output of $act does not support the object that it creates as a result. So i had to create New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup and then assign ActionGroupId to it. 
There is no proper documentation on Microsoft Website about it.

Comment: Strange I used the exact same that was given as an example in their documentation  and it works fine. What matters is that you found a way around it.

Comment: Thanks for you help anyways. May be you can help me with the other thing as well. I am trying to create new WebTest under new Alerts and not able to do that so far. Have you tried ?

Comment: Hi I am currently working on automating these things. So I can give you feedback soon, for example I can try tomorrow or the weekend.

Comment: Sure i am trying on my end as well. Found one ARM Template but getting some errors.

Comment: Ok sure, one way to do it please edit your comment and add the second part where you want to create a WebTest and lets see if we can figure it out.

Comment: This is what i found that we need to add to template but it did not work for me.

Comment: Finally i managed to create webtest and alerts. I used separate template to create both of them. First i created webtests(using old template form MS website) and then modified below mentioned template and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Resource Explorer and navigate to a manually created (near-realtime) alert, you should see the "critera" object defined like below.  Here is a full example of a resource that seems to be working.  Create some variables for each of your values:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts",
  "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
  "name": "[variables('alertName')]",
  "location": "global",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-link:', variables('applicationInsightsResourceId'))]": "Resource",
    "[concat('hidden-link:', variables('webtestResourceId'))]": "Resource"
  },
  "properties": {
    "description": "[concat('Alert for ', parameters('availibilityTestName'))]",
    "severity": 4,
    "enabled": true,
    "scopes": [
      "[variables('webtestResourceId')]",
      "[variables('applicationInsightsResourceId')]"
    ],
    "evaluationFrequency": "PT5M",
    "windowSize": "PT15M",
    "criteria": {
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.WebtestLocationAvailabilityCriteria",
      "webTestId": "[variables('webtestResourceId')]",
      "componentId": "[variables('applicationInsightsResourceId')]",
      "failedLocationCount": 3
    },
    "actions": [
      {
        "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actiongroups', 'webhook')]",
        "webHookProperties": {
           // Some properties to send to webhook
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```